# Determining the separability of 3D kernels (Can a 1D kernel get the result of 3D convolution?)

Tags: matlab, kernel

I have three kernels of size `2×2×2` (as define below by `ker1`, `ker2`, `ker3`). I wanted to know how I can determine whether these kernels are separable (for `3D` convolution purposes). I read [online](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/11/28/separable-convolution-part-2/) how this can be done in `MATLAB` for `2D` kernels. But rank of a `3D` array! mmmm, I don't think there's such thing. Maybe other methods?

**The main question is: can a `1D` kernel get the result of 3D convolution (not using FFT)?**

`MATLAB` command `convn` is very fast for computation of the convolution of the 3D array. However, I am writing a standalone `C++` application separate from `MATLAB` and cannot use `convn` in my code. If separability of the above mentioned kernels can be determined, it will greatly help me use `1D` convolution in my code, which is also easy to implement.

I would be thankful to have the thoughts of my friends in the community on this matter.

```
>> % I am investigating this in MATLAB
ker1(:,:,1) =
    -1     1
    -1     1
ker1(:,:,2) =
    -1     1
    -1     1

>> 
ker2(:,:,1) =
    -1    -1
    -1    -1
ker2(:,:,2) =
     1     1
     1     1

>> 
ker3(:,:,1) =
    -1    -1
     1     1
ker3(:,:,2) =
    -1    -1
     1     1

>> my3Darray = ones( 200,200,200 );
>> res1 = convn( my3Darray, ker1 );
>> res2 = convn( my3Darray, ker2 );
>> res3 = convn( my3Darray, ker3 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all these three tensors can be written as the outer product `*` of three vectors `a*b*c`.

1. `ker1 = [ 1,1] * [-1,1] * [ 1,1]`
2. `ker2 = [ 1,1] * [ 1,1] * [-1,1]`
3. `ker3 = [-1,1] * [ 1,1] * [ 1,1]`

(This of course is not Matlab syntax. You can think of the first vector as column-vector, the second as row vector and the third as 'top'-vector.)

Comment: Fantastic. Can you please comment on the implementation as well? My understanding is that I first apply 1D convolution with column-vector, then I use the result and apply the row-vector kernel to it, and finally the top-vector. Also is there a general way of checking separability? Please advise.

Comment: Yes. Individual 1D convolution of all columns with column-vector -> Individual 1D convolution of all resulting rows with row-vector -> Individual 1D convolution of all resulting 'top'-vectors with the top-vector -> result. The order of this process shouldn't matter by the way.